# Is it possible to push code into bitbucket into a non-existent repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, bitbucket-server

My project structure is as below:

```
Project1:
--Repository 1
--Repository 2
--Repository 3
--
--
--Repository 8
```

I use bitbucket and I have the Project1 created already. But I don't want to create the repositories manually. Also I have the code with history intact in my local machine. By pushing this code into bitbucket for the first time, will it automatically create the repository in bitbucket?

My code:

```
git remote add origin https://User@bitbucket.org/scm/proj1/repos1.git
git remote set-url origin https://User@bitbucket.org/scm/proj1/repos1.git
git push -u origin master
```

I am getting the below error:

```
fatal: NullReferenceException encountered.
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
fatal: remote error: Repository not found
The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to
access it.
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? I don't want to create repos manually. Instead when I push the code under a specific project will bitbucket create the repository for the first time by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Since a repository *must* be created before, you could script that creation, using the [BitBucket Could API `/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}`](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#post) (a BitBucket server has a [different API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/4.8.3/bitbucket-rest.html#idp2410912))

That way, your script could loop on your local folders, and for each one, create the corresponding remote repository, as well as add the `origin` config on each subfolders.

Comment: Awesome. I can try this. Can I do the steps you mentioned in gitbash/CLI itself?

Comment: @Rick Yes (I assume by git bash a Windows bash session through git bash). It depends on the remote server though: BitBucket Cloud or server.